# Redirect from one image to another between servers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need make one redirect - from images on one server to new path on second server.
For example
I have url
http://example.com/images/main?image=http://example2.com/type/big/picture1.jpg

How can I do redirect with htaccess and get image "http://example.com/type/big/picture1.jpg"

I tried so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} images\/main\/.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} from=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [NC,L]
```

I checked - $1 - its REQUEST_URI, but I need QUERY_STRING
If I replace $1 to defined image - it's ok, but I need use this for many images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code below rewrite  http://example.com/images/main?**from**=http://example2.com/type/big/picture1.jpg to http://example.com/type/big/picture1.jpg

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/main$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} from=http://example2.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1? [NC,L]
```

Comment: I need another.
I need redirect file http://example.com/images/main?from=http://example2.com/type/big/picture1.jpg
to file
http://example2.com/type/big/picture1.jpg

Comment: But in any cases thank you for help, I use %1 instead of $1 - and work.